# Help me correct/understand the harmonic analysis of this

Tags: theory, chords, harmony, roman-numerals, chord-inversions

Am I missing something here? (Note: the circled notes aren't included so we just ignore that. I'm only trying to analyze the rest.) In measure 8 (the second measure in the below excerpt), after Em, I don't need to add a chord there (as told), so I was wondering if there's anything wrong with my answers here. This isn't a specific piece. Are there secondary dominants here?

[image: measures 7 and 8, plus pickup beat]

Comment: The 8th measure after Em?

Comment: @Aaron there is a measure number "6" at the beginning of the excerpt, and there is a comma missing in the question between "measure" and "after."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two eighth notes on the first beat are both uncircled, making the chord a C# half-diminished.

However, it's unclear whether the exercise is intended to include seventh chords. If it's triads only, then the analysis is fine. The `ii` chord is just linking the two `I` chord inversions. An alternative analysis would be to consider the `B` in the `ii` chord as an accented passing tone and instead analyze the chord as `viio6`. It's functionally the same, but might seem more intuitive to think of a `vii` chord leading back to `I`, since that's a more common situation than a `ii` chord operating the same way.

There are no secondary dominants.

Comment: What was wrong with vii half-diminished 6/5 as a chord label on Bar 8?

Comment: @Dekkadeci Just a more unusual choice, and seventh chords seemed beyond the scope of the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Aaron's answer - there are no secondary dominants. The reason being a secondary dominant essentially, is the V of any of the chords diatonic to that key - not including the V of the tonic itself, of course - that's simply *the* dominant.

So, in key D, F♯7 (V of Bm), B7, (V of Em), C♯7 (V of F♯m), E7 (V of A), would be examples.